# How to create a DST type?

Tags: rust

DST (Dynamically Sized Types) are a thing in Rust now. I have *used* them successfully, with a flexible last member which is known to the compiler (such as `[u8]`).

What I am looking to do, however, is to create a custom DST. Say, for example:

```
struct Known<S> {
    dropit: fn (&mut S) -> (),
    data: S,
}

struct Unknown {
    dropit: fn (&mut ()) -> (),
    data: (),
}
```

With an expected usage being `Box<Known<S>>` => `Box<Unknown>` => `Box<Known<S>>`, where the middleware need not know about concrete types.

*Note: yes, I know about `Any`, and no I am not interested in using it.*

I am open to suggestions in the layout of both `Known` and `Unknown`, however:

1. `size_of::<Box<Known>>() = size_of::<Box<Unknown>>() = size_of::<Box<u32>>()`; that is it should be a thin pointer.
2. dropping `Box<Unknown>` drops its content
3. cloning `Box<Unknown>` (assuming a clonable `S`), clones its content
4. ideally, `fn dup(u: &Unknown) -> Box<Unknown> { box u.clone() }` works

I have particular difficulties with (3) and (4), I could solve (3) with manually allocating memory (not using `box`, but directly calling `malloc`) but I would prefer providing an idiomatic experience to the user.

I could not find any documentation on how to inform `box` of the right size to allocate.

Comment: This thing is different enough from everything in the standard library (that I know of) that implementing it manually, with `unsafe` code, is probably the easiest, most reliable, and all around best option. It most likely won't fit into the existing DST scheme or into Box.

Comment: There are exactly two types of unsized objects: slices (`[T]`), where it adds a length member; and trait objects (`Trait`, `Trait + Send`, *&c.*), where it adds a vtable including a destructor which knows how large an object to free. There is no mechanism for declaring your own variety of unsized objects.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan: Humpf... I was kind of afraid of that... May I suppose thus that `box` allocates based on `std::mem::size_of`?

Comment: @MatthieuM.: it would add significant complexity, which has not been justified yet; until such a time it will be at best a very low-priority task.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan: Oh sure, I am trying to understand how Rust works at low-level; not being able to use `box` syntax is annoying, but it's not necessarily a show-stopper.

Comment: `box` syntax is definitely not stable yet; placement new hasn’t even been implemented, for example. And that’s something that’s definitely higher priority than custom types of unsized types!

Comment: @ChrisMorgan: Sure, I'd just be glad to understand how the current box syntax works.

Comment: At the moment, the answer is sadly “magic”.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan: Would you formalize all this in an answer? After all, "Not possible" is a perfectly valid answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are exactly two types of unsized objects at present: slices (`[T]`), where it adds a length member; and trait objects (`Trait`, `Trait + Send`, *&c.*), where it adds a vtable including a destructor which knows how large an object to free.

There is not currently any mechanism for declaring your own variety of unsized objects.

Comment: This is correct, but there is a third class of DST, `struct Foo<T: ?Sized>`; *however*, it must be parameterized by one of the three classes, which fundamentally comes down to using one of the *two* DST classes of traits or slices in the lowest level.

Answer (score 1):

At this point, you should seek inspiration from [`Arc::new_uinint_slice`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html#method.new_uninit_slice) and [`Arc::from_ptr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/sync.rs.html#212-220).

We've no nice mechanism to make custom DSTs play nicely together though, making `Arc<Known<T>>` nasty.

We still always create `Arc<dyn Trait>` with `CoerceUnsized` because you cannot make trait objects form DSTs currently.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using [the vptr crate](https://docs.rs/vptr/0.2.1/vptr/), which stores the vtable pointer with the data instead of with the pointer.