# How to safely construct fat pointers/pointers to DSTs of LV2 atoms in Rust?

Tags: pointers, types, reference, rust, unsafe

I am working on an integration of LV2 atoms for Rust, which are slice-based dynamically sized types (DSTs). In general, atoms are created by the host or other plugins and my code receives only a thin pointer to them. Therefore, I need to create a fat pointer to a slice-based DST from a thin pointer. This is how my code roughly looks like:

```
#[repr(C)]
struct Atom {
    /// The len of the `data` field.
    len: u32,
    /// The data. 
    data: [u8],
}

/// This is the host. It creates the atom in a generally unknown way and calls
/// the plugin's run function. This isn't really part of my code, but it is
/// needed to understand it.
fn host() {
    // The raw representation of the atom
    let raw_representation: [u8; 8] = [
        // len: Raw representation of a `u32`. We have four data bytes.
        4, 0, 0, 0,
        // The actual data:
        1, 2, 3, 4
    ];

    let ptr: *const u8 = raw_representation.as_ptr();

    plugin_run(ptr);
}

/// This function represents the plugin's run function:
/// It only knows the pointer to the atom, nothing more.
fn plugin_run(ptr: *const u8) {
    // The length of the data.
    let len: u32 = *unsafe { (ptr as *const u32).as_ref() }.unwrap();

    // The "true" representation of the fat pointer.
    let fat_pointer: (*const u8, usize) = (ptr, len as usize);

    // transmuting the tuple into the actuall raw pointer.
    let atom: *const Atom = unsafe { std::mem::transmute(fat_pointer) };

    println!("{:?}", &atom.data);
}
```

The interesting line is the penultimate line in `plugin_run`: Here, a fat pointer is created by transmuting a tuple containing the thin pointer and the length. This approach works, but it uses the highly unsafe [`transmute`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.transmute.html) method. According to the documentation, this method should be the absolute last resort, but as far as I understand the design of Rust, I'm doing nothing that should be unsafe. I'm just creating a pointer!

I don't want to stick with this solution. Is there a safe way to create pointers to array-based structs apart from using `transmute`?

The only thing that goes in this direction is [`std::slice::from_raw_parts`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/fn.from_raw_parts.html), but it is also unsafe, directly creates a reference, not a pointer, and works exclusively for slices. I found nothing in the standard library, I found nothing on crates.io, I even found no issues in the git repo.  Am I searching for the wrong keywords? Is something like this actually welcome in Rust?

If nothing like this exists, I would go forth and create an issue for that in Rust's Github repo.

EDIT: I shouldn't have said something about LV2, it made the discussion go in a completely different direction. Everything works just fine, I've deeply thought about the data models and tested it; The only thing I would like to have is a safe alternative to using `transmute` to create fat pointers. :(

Comment: I believe your question is answered by the answers of [How to create a DST type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30174822/how-to-create-a-dst-type). If you disagree, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: This question is about how to create your own "kind" of DST type, since there are only two "kind"s of DSTs in Rust: Arrays and trait objects. These base DST types can be used to create new "derived" DSTs. I don't want to create a new "kind" of DST, I want to create a pointer to an array-based DST without using unsafe code. I will edit my question to clear this up.

Comment: Then perhaps [How do you actually use dynamically sized types in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25740916/155423) is relevant.

Comment: Does `Atom` actually have other (sized) fields besides `data` and `len`?

Comment: C doesn't have fat pointer or `DST` so you will have to precise what your hypothetical C API is doing. I check a little on http://drobilla.net/docs/lilv/ doesn't give me much information. Your `Atom` structure is not C compatible see https://stackoverflow.com/a/53050526/1233251. So, If you want to do Rust-to-C, your question don't make sense.

Comment: Do you actually need a fat pointer to manipulate this in Rust code? If the value is always constructed outside of Rust, then can't you just refer to it via a normal reference, `&Atom`, assuming you can make guarantees about its lifetime or a `*const Atom` if not?

Comment: Perhaps also via an opaque pointer: [What's the Rust idiom to define a field pointing to a C opaque pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38315383/155423)

Comment: Sorry for not testing my code before posting, I should have done that. Also: Yes, C can't express DSTs, but No, Atoms are dynamically sized types: The general idea of an atom is that it has a sized header in the beginning and then an arbitrary, _dynamic_ amount of bytes followed. Also, I have a good argument for this model being compatible with C: It works in my project! ([project](https://github.com/Janonard/lv2rs.git), [examples](https://github.com/Janonard/lv2rs-book.git) )

Comment: "Everything works just fine, I've deeply thought about the data models and tested it;" I really doubt about that. looking by your code what you do is incorrect

Comment: Please, keep update this question as you go though your project but I think you should look at FAM in C and how bindgen [handle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53055574/7076153) them (you should do something similar), also, forget about the idea to create the fat pointer yourself in Rust that will not help you to make better code.

Comment: See also [Is it possible to have stack allocated arrays with the size determined at runtime in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27859822/155423)

Comment: "forget about the idea to create the fat pointer yourself in Rust" Why should I forget about fat pointers? Could you explain that? Is it because the raw representation of fat pointer isn't stable across versions or architectures? I mean, slices are fat pointers too and the `from_raw_parts` method also constructs them in a similar way (It uses a union instead of `transmute`, but it's basically the same). The way `from_raw_parts` handles fat pointers even inspired me to use this approach.

Answer (score -1):

## Assuming you want dynamic-sized-types

Change your type to a generic one that allows an unsized parameter that defaults to `[u8]`. Then you can take a concrete value and get the unsized version:

```rust
#[repr(C)]
struct Atom<D: ?Sized = [u8]> {
    /// The len of the `data` field.
    len: u32,
    /// The data.
    data: D,
}

fn main() {
    let a1: &Atom = &Atom {
        len: 12,
        data: [1, 2, 3],
    };

    let a2: Box<Atom> = Box::new(Atom {
        len: 34,
        data: [4, 5, 6],
    });
}
```

See also:

- [How do you actually use dynamically sized types in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25740916/155423)

## Assuming you want LV2 atoms

> I am working on an integration of LV2 atoms for Rust

Is there a reason you are not using the [existing crate that deals with this](https://docs.rs/lv2_raw/)?

> LV2 atoms for Rust, which are slice-based dynamically sized types

They are not, according to [the source code I could find](https://github.com/x42/lv2vst/blob/c6a66b442baf218b5ad56c83ff4ce0bc7c0c4932/include/lv2/lv2plug.in/ns/ext/atom/atom.h). Instead, it only uses structural composition:

```c
typedef struct {
    uint32_t size;  /**< Size in bytes, not including type and size. */
    uint32_t type;  /**< Type of this atom (mapped URI). */
} LV2_Atom;

/** An atom:Int or atom:Bool.  May be cast to LV2_Atom. */
typedef struct {
    LV2_Atom atom;  /**< Atom header. */
    int32_t  body;  /**< Integer value. */
} LV2_Atom_Int;
```

The [official documentation](http://lv2plug.in/doc/html/group__atom.html) appears to agree. This means that it would likely be invalid to ever take an `LV2_Atom` by value as you'd only copy the header, not the body. This is commonly referred to as *struct tearing*.

---

In Rust, this could be implemented as:

```
use libc::{int32_t, uint32_t};

#[repr(C)]
struct Atom {
    size: uint32_t,
    r#type: uint32_t,
}

#[repr(C)]
struct Int {
    atom: Atom,
    body: int32_t,
}

const INT_TYPE: uint32_t = 42; // Not real

extern "C" {
    fn get_some_atom() -> *const Atom;
}

fn get_int() -> Option<*const Int> {
    unsafe {
        let a = get_some_atom();
        if (*a).r#type == INT_TYPE {
            Some(a as *const Int)
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}

fn use_int() {
    if let Some(i) = get_int() {
        let val = unsafe { (*i).body };
        println!("{}", val);
    }
}
```

If you look at the source code for the [lv2_raw crate](https://crates.io/crates/lv2_raw), you'll see much the same thing. There's also a [lv2 crate](https://crates.io/crates/lv2) that attempts to bring a higher-level interface.

Comment: I'm sorry, but that doesn't solve the problem. The problem is about how to safely create a fat pointer to an array-based type, not if LV2 atoms are DSTs or not. I shouldn't have said something about LV2, it made the discussion go in a completely wrong direction. Everything works fine, I just want to have a safe alternative to `transmute` :(