# How to create a smart pointer to an unsized type with an embedded slice?

Tags: rust, smart-pointers

I'm trying to avoid multiple heap allocations by using something like C's flexible-array member. For that, I need to allocate an unsized struct, but I didn't find any way to do that through smart pointers. I'm specifically interested in `Rc`, but this is also the case for `Box`, so that's what I'll use in the example.

Here is the closest I've gotten so far:

```rust
use std::alloc::{self, Layout};

struct Inner {/* Sized fields */}

#[repr(C)] // Ensure the array is always last
// Both `inner` and `arr` need to be allocated, but preferably not separately
struct Unsized {
    inner: Inner,
    arr: [usize],
}

pub struct Exposed(Box<Unsized>);

impl Exposed {
    pub fn new(capacity: usize) -> Self {
        // Create a layout of an `Inner` followed by the array
        let (layout, arr_base) = Layout::array::<usize>(capacity)
            .and_then(|arr_layout| Layout::new::<Inner>().extend(arr_layout))
            .unwrap();
        let ptr = unsafe { alloc::alloc(layout) };
        // At this point, `ptr` is `*mut u8` and the compiler doesn't know the size of the allocation
        if ptr.is_null() {
            panic!("Internal allocation error");
        }
        unsafe {
            ptr.cast::<Inner>()
                .write(Inner {/* Initialize sized fields */});
            let tmp_ptr = ptr.add(arr_base).cast::<usize>();
            // Initialize the array elements, in this case to 0
            (0..capacity).for_each(|i| tmp_ptr.add(i).write(0));
            // At this point everything is initialized and can safely be converted to `Box`
            Self(Box::from_raw(ptr as *mut _))
        }
    }
}
```

This doesn't compile:

```
error[E0607]: cannot cast thin pointer `*mut u8` to fat pointer `*mut Unsized`
  --> src/lib.rs:32:28
   |
32 |         Self(Box::from_raw(ptr as *mut _))
   |                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I could work directly with `*mut u8`, but that seems extremely error-prone and requires manual dropping.

Is there a way to create a fat pointer from `ptr`, since I actually know the allocation size, or to create a smart pointer from a compound unsized type?

Comment: Is `Exposed` restricted to being two words wide? If not, you could define `pub struct Exposed(Inner, Box<[usize]>)`. You would still have only one allocation, and you would need no unsafe.

Comment: Relevant open RFCs: [Introduce Pointee and DynSized](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/2984); [Pointer metadata & VTable](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/2580); [Procedural vtables and fully customizeable wide pointers](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/2967).

Comment: @user4815162342 Sorry, I forgort to mention that `Inner` also needs to be allocated. I will edit the question to include that. Also, it is preferable that `Exposed` isn't big.

Comment: See also [How do you actually use dynamically sized types in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25740916/155423); [How to create a DST type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30174822/155423);

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that the pointer `*mut Unsized` is a wide pointer, so not just an address, but an address and the number of elements in the slice. The pointer `*mut u8` on the other hand contains no information about the length of the slice. The standard library supplies the

- `std::ptr::slice_from_raw_parts` and,
- `std::ptr::slice_from_raw_parts_mut`

for this situtation. So you first create a fake (and wrong) `*mut usize`

```
ptr as *mut usize
```

which then allows

```
slice_from_raw_parts_mut(ptr as *mut usize, capacity)
```

to create a fake (and still wrong) `*mut [usize]` with the correct length field in the wide pointer, which we then unceremonously cast

```
slice_from_raw_parts_mut(ptr as *mut usize, capacity) as *mut Unsized
```

which does nothing but change the type (the value is unchanged), so we get the correct pointer that we can now finally feed into `Box::from_raw`

Full example demonstrating this post:

```rust
use std::alloc::{self, Layout};

struct Inner {/* Sized fields */}

#[repr(C)] // Ensure the array is always last
           // Both `inner` and `arr` need to be allocated, but preferably not separately
struct Unsized {
    inner: Inner,
    arr: [usize],
}

pub struct Exposed(Box<Unsized>);

impl Exposed {
    pub fn new(capacity: usize) -> Self {
        // Create a layout of an `Inner` followed by the array
        let (layout, arr_base) = Layout::array::<usize>(capacity)
            .and_then(|arr_layout| Layout::new::<Inner>().extend(arr_layout))
            .unwrap();
        let ptr = unsafe { alloc::alloc(layout) };
        // At this point, `ptr` is `*mut u8` and the compiler doesn't know the size of the allocation
        if ptr.is_null() {
            panic!("Internal allocation error");
        }
        unsafe {
            ptr.cast::<Inner>()
                .write(Inner {/* Initialize sized fields */});
            let tmp_ptr = ptr.add(arr_base).cast::<usize>();
            // Initialize the array elements, in this case to 0
            (0..capacity).for_each(|i| tmp_ptr.add(i).write(0));
        }

        // At this point everything is initialized and can safely be converted to `Box`
        unsafe {
            Self(Box::from_raw(
                std::ptr::slice_from_raw_parts_mut(ptr as *mut usize, capacity) as *mut Unsized,
            ))
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f10c4a661db7653a329019c99c58c3f1)

---

Side note: You do not need `#[repr(C)]` to make sure that the unsized slice field is at the end, that is guaranteed. What you need it for is knowing the offsets to the fields.

Comment: Thanks, that looks like the right direction. However, doesn't this method create a fat pointer only to the size of the `arr` member of `Unsized`? (I think I can figure it out from here, just wanted to clarify)

Comment: @chuck what do you mean by "only to the size of the `arr` member"?

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think this works only in the case that `mem::size_of::<Inner>() == 0` (I probably shouldn't have done this in the example). However if this is not the case I guess `std::ptr::slice_from_raw_parts(ptr, capacity * mem::size_of::<usize> + mem::size_of::<Inner>()) as *mut Unsized` can be used, so the answer still solves the problem.

Comment: @chuck I changed `Inner` to `struct Inner(bool)` and it continued to work (and passed Miri).

Comment: Then I'm confused - shouldn't the size of the slice passed to `Box::from_raw` be the same as `layout.size()`?

Comment: @chuck what do you mean by "size of the slice"? All slices are fat pointers (equivalent to two `usize`) and the same size.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222251/discussion-between-chuck-and-shepmaster).