# How to place an array of structs at the end of another struct without memory segmentation

Tags: rust, memory, memory-management

I'm in the process of porting a low latency real-time application to Rust. Essentially I want to do as much as possible of the operations without copying. A major source of memory allocations right now are coming from the network stack. Every time a packet is received or send a lot of copying goes on under the hood to force and retrieve the bytes from a Rust structs. I want to stop doing this.

Essentially I want to be able to just convert the packets from/to bytes and transmit it. Below is a non-working example code that illustrates what I would like to do.

```
#[repr(C, align(4))]
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Content {
    first: u8,
    padding: [u8; 3]
}

#[repr(C, align(4))]
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Packet {
    header_id: u16,
    header_padding: [u8; 2],
    // This is another pointer I want it to be located after header_padding
    content: Box<[Content]>,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct ParsedPacket {
    content_length: usize,
    // The box below should directly reference the original u8 bytes without copying
    packet: Box<Packet>,
}

unsafe fn buf_to_packet(bs: Box<[u8]>) -> Option<Box<ParsedPacket>> {
    // How to implement this
    // First 4 bytes are the header
    // The rest must be 4 byte multiple and each 4 byte is a Content struct
    // So from the length of the boxed slice we can infer the content_length
    todo!()
}

unsafe fn packet_to_buf(bs: ParsedPacket) -> Box<[u8]> {
    todo!()
}

fn main() {
    let bytes = vec![
        // Header
        0, 23, 0, 0,
        // Content 0
        0, 0, 0, 0,
        // Content 1
        1, 0, 0, 0,
        // Content 2
        0, 0, 0, 0
    ].into_boxed_slice();

    let packet = unsafe { buf_to_packet(bytes) };

    println!("{:?}", content);
}
```

There are two problems with this. Rust requires the content to be a boxed slice. Which mains it necessarily isn't located in the struct itself but might be somewhere else. Also a boxed slice contains it's own bookkeeping about the length. I guess I need to do my own bookkeeping with the length. But I don't know how I can add a struct member with dynamic length without using a boxed slice.

I am of course willing to use unsafe to do it. But I'm not experienced with Rust so I don't know how I can actually implement this.

Essentially what I'm looking for in Rust is [Flexible array members](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member) from C.

Comment: `buf_to_packet` is not possible with `Box` and probably not very usable with references since the byte slice will most likely not be aligned properly. For a `Box<Packet>` the pointer has to be allocated with the exact same alignment which `[u8]` doesn't have.

Comment: @cafce25 You can assume 4-byte alignment. It's not really the crux of the question.

Comment: If you can assume alignment, start by changing `Box<[Content]>` to just `[Content]`.

Comment: Look into Unsize Coercion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Rust this is called a [dynamically sized type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/exotic-sizes.html#dynamically-sized-types-dsts) (DST) which commonly covers trait objects and slices but you can make custom DSTs even though support spotty at best (through use of `unsafe` and nightly features for functionality like this).

To make your struct into a custom DST (and act similar to a flexible array member in C), you simply make the last member into a bare slice like so:

```
#[repr(C, align(4))]
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Packet {
    header_id: u16,
    header_padding: [u8; 2],
    content: [Content],
}
```

To "cast" from bytes to a `Packet` the bytes must first be aligned. This will commonly be 8-byte aligned already on many modern systems, but in case that can't be relied on, you can use the trick here: [How do I allocate a Vec that is aligned to the size of the cache line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60180121/how-do-i-allocate-a-vecu8-that-is-aligned-to-the-size-of-the-cache-line) Because of alignment and allocation restrictions, its much easier to create a `&Packet` than a `Box<Packet>`.

Then to properly manipulate "fat pointers" that are used to express indirection to DSTs, we'll need to rely on the unstable feature [`ptr_metadata`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/81513). Putting that to use yields this:

```
#![feature(ptr_metadata, pointer_is_aligned)]

#[repr(C, align(4))]
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Content {
    first: u8,
    padding: [u8; 3]
}

#[repr(C, align(4))]
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Packet {
    header_id: u16,
    header_padding: [u8; 2],
    content: [Content],
}

fn buf_to_packet(bytes: &[u8]) -> Option<&Packet> {
    const PACKET_HEADER_LEN: usize = 4;

    let bytes_len = bytes.len();
    let bytes_ptr = bytes.as_ptr();
    if bytes_len < PACKET_HEADER_LEN || !bytes_ptr.is_aligned_to(4) {
        return None;
    }

    let content_len = (bytes_len - PACKET_HEADER_LEN) / std::mem::size_of::<Content>();
    let packet_raw: *const Packet = std::ptr::from_raw_parts(bytes_ptr.cast(), content_len);

    // SAFETY: the pointer is aligned and initialized
    unsafe { packet_raw.as_ref() }
}
```

See also:

- [Here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=bb264ef8d471a4c734427d03f82fcddf) is a code sample that demonstrates what you'd need to know if you actually needed to create a `Box<Packet>` from a `Box<u8>`.
- [How to create a smart pointer to an unsized type with an embedded slice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64120001/how-to-create-a-smart-pointer-to-an-unsized-type-with-an-embedded-slice) for more info how you might allocate a `Box<Packet>` from nothing.

Comment: Instead of reversing the packet back to `Box<[u8]>` when deallocating, you can have `#[repr(transparent, align(4))] struct U8Wrapper(u8);` and allocate a `Box<[U8Wrapper]>`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman You can't have `transparent` and `align(4)` at the same time (kinda defeats the purpose of `transparent`). But yes, if you ensure the layout (size and alignment) during allocation matches the layout you deallocate (as `Packet`), then that avoids the `Drop` logic.

Comment: Then `#[repr(C, align(4))]`.

Comment: Just noticed that what I suggested is impossible since the size has to be a multiply of the alignment.